# Spring MVC: Mapping Multiple URLs to Same Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have like 20+ forms which are linked from the same page. Some forms share the same controller, while others use their own. For example, form `A`, `B`, and `C` use `DefaultController`, while form `D` uses `ControllerD`.

*What I would like to achieve is to map the URL to each form in a consistent way.*

So, ideally, the link page would look like :

- either this

  ```
  <a href="/formA.html">Form A</a>
  <a href="/formB.html">Form B</a>
  <a href="/formC.html">Form C</a>
  <a href="/formD.html">Form D</a>
  ```
- or this:

  ```
  <a href="/form.html?name=A">Form A</a>
  <a href="/form.html?name=B">Form B</a>
  <a href="/form.html?name=C">Form C</a>
  <a href="/form.html?name=D">Form D</a>
  ```

The question is how to map each URL to the appropriate controller. With the first URL pattern, you would map `formD.html` to `ControllerD`, but not sure how to map `form[A|B|C].html` to `DefaultController`. With the second URL pattern, I don't even know where to begin...

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 186):

Since nobody seems to have put the full answer on here yet:

The `@RequestMapping` annotation can take an array for its "value" parameter. To map this at the controller level using the first pattern, you would use:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/formA.html", "/formB.html", "/formC.html"})
public class ControllerA {

}
```

And then:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/formD.html")
public class ControllerD {

}
```

Comment: I put this on my method instead of the controller and it works great.