# how can I make mapping two types of url for one webpage

Tags: java, jquery

I want to make one page with two types of url. 
One is http://www.test.com/1234 
The other one is http://www.test.com/addDetail

I am developing on Spring framework and use jSP + JQuery. 
How can I make one page with two urls?
If you have some ideas or any way, please let me know. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this question has already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898442/spring-mvc-mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-controller).

You can try the following code for your controller which you want to handle both URL requests:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/1234", "/addDetail"})
public class YourControllerHere {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. BTW I got a 400 bad request error after doing you said. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing one of the values and see if that works.  For example: @RequestMapping("/1234").  Navigate to http://www.test.com/1234 and see what happens.  If you still get that error then you should probably have a look at your web.xml and other Spring configuration files.