# Accessing multiple controllers with same request mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Please find my HomeController and DemoController

```
class HomeController{
@RequestMapping(value="index")
public void home(){
}
}

class DemoController{
@RequestMapping(value="index")
public void demo(){
}
}
```

when I try to send a request to index, which one will get executed?
I wanted to know how can we have same request mapping value for multiple controllers

Comment: You cannot. A URL can only be mapped to a single controller. It has to be unique.

Comment: Note that this would be meaningless anyway. The whole point of a URL is that it tells you where to get something.

Comment: It is not meaningless when you use controllers to separate a big number of methods, but adding an extra fragment to every method which differentiates it, that way the path is still unique as every method has different mapping, there are not collisions. However spring mvc seems to disallow that.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping (Did you try and run it for yourself?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [Spring Web MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) this is not possible. Each mapping must be unique in your context. If not, you will receive a `RuntimeException` during context initialization.

You cannot even use parameters to differentiate your endpoints because they are not evaluated while searching for a suitable handler (applicable for Servlet environments). From [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) javadoc:

> In a Servlet environment, parameter mappings are considered as restrictions that are enforced at the type level. The primary path mapping (i.e. the specified URI value) still has to uniquely identify the target handler, with parameter mappings simply expressing preconditions for invoking the handler.

Note that you can do the opposite, so multiple URLs can point to the same handler. Have a look at [Spring MVC: Mapping Multiple URLs to Same Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898442/spring-mvc-mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-controller)

Comment: That documentation is at least partially out of date. Thanks for mentioning it; I'll examine and may open a doc issue.

Comment: @Marco Ferrari what happens if i want to create two controllers classes with the same RequstMapping and each have different Methods and different method RequestMappings

Comment: @MeladEzzat it's acceptable. Try it by a quick edit of the Boot's getting started [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Answer (score 26):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590355/2682499 is only partially correct at this point.

You **can** have multiple controller methods use the same URI so long as you provide Spring enough additional information on which one it should use.  Whether or not you *should* do this is a different question.  I would certainly not recommend using the same URI in two separate controller classes to avoid confusion, though.

You *can* do something like this:

```
class HomeController{
    @RequestMapping(value="/index", params = {"!name", "!foo"})
    public List<Something> listItems(){
        // retrieve Something list
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/index", params = "name")
    public List<Something> listItems(String name) {
        // retrieve Something list WHERE name LIKE %name%
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/index", params = {"!name", "foo"})
    public List<Something> listItems(String foo) {
        // Do something completely different
    }
}
```

For the full documentation on what is possible when overloading URIs you should reference the @ReqeustMapping documentation:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html. And, specifically https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params-- for the section request parameters.

Comment: I think the question is about whether it is possible to use the same `@RequestMapping` in two controllers whereas your answer explains how to use the same `@RequestMapping` multiple times in a single controller.

Comment: My example is applicable to using the same request mapping in the same or multiple controllers.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The request mapping has to be unique otherwise the application can't determine which method the incoming request should be mapped to.

What you can do instead is to extend the request mapping:

```
class HomeController{

   @RequestMapping(value="home/index")
   public void home(){
   }
}

class DemoController{

   @RequestMapping(value="demo/index")
   public void demo(){
   }
}
```