# Can i overload action by request param in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can I overload action by request param in spring MVC?
similarly to ASP.NET MVC.

The following code runs successfully, however only the method with parameter is called

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Home")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){

        return new ModelAndView();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index",method = RequestMethod.GET,params={"data"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String index(@RequestParam String data){

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: did this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587254/accessing-multiple-controllers-with-same-request-mapping

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing multiple controllers with same request mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587254/accessing-multiple-controllers-with-same-request-mapping)