# How to overload Spring Boot RestController methods that use @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, overloading

I'm interested in overloading an `@PostMapping` of say, /digital/testCase, with two separate signatures, that use `@RequestBody` annotations to pass data, rather than `@RequestParams`. This is important, because all of the other questions on StackOverflow pertain to the latter. Currently, Spring Boot crashes when I try overload a function.

For those interested in seeing the code, it would look something like this

```
package com.example.test;

import *

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/digital", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public class TestController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @Autowired
    private testDomain testDomain;


    @PostMapping("/testCase")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> testCase(@RequestBody InitiateTestCase initiateTestCase,
                                               HttpServletRequest request) {

        //
        ...some code here
        //
    }

    @PostMapping("/testCase")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> testCase(@RequestBody InitiateTestCase[] initiateTestCases,
                                               HttpServletRequest request) {

        //
        ...some code here
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is not available in spring

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590355/7237884

Comment: How, precisely, do you expect Spring to distinguish an incoming call between your two controller methods?

Comment: This won't work as it will lead to a single URL being mapped to 2 methods. Spring cannot distinguish which one to call. The stuff in `@PostMapping` is used for mapping the incoming request to a method, the combinations of attributes has to be unique for each method.

Comment: @chrylis - well, I was hoping and/or thinking to myself that ideally Spring could proactively compare the JSON structure to the two RequestBody definitions, and if it matched one, use that method...  I suppose I might actually be interested in writing that as a wrapper method (e.g. the URL hits the wrapper method). And then let the wrapper method use overloading to call the functions... ideally, overloading (or some workable substitute, like functional chains) needs to happen, because the URL being hit must accept a variety of formatting for these cases based on project needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add some specific params/headers to PostMapping annotation so Spring will be able to map it properly. Another way of solving such problem is to abstract your pojo used as RequestBody and not overload methods.