# Springboot Rest controllers with same request mapping

Tags: spring-boot, rest

Can I have more than one Springboot Rest controllers with same request mapping? I need to call the appropriate controller based on the RequestHeader. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot, it's not possible to have multiple controllers with the exact same @RequestMapping value in the same application context. This would result in a conflict, and Spring wouldn't be able to determine which controller to use for a given request.

However, you can achieve the desired behavior by using different @RequestMapping values for each controller and then determining which controller to invoke based on the RequestHeader values.

You can refer to this post [Stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587254/accessing-multiple-controllers-with-same-request-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple controllers with the same @RequestMapping would result in Spring not being able to distinguish between them, when processing the request path.
For example, this would result in run time error:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/same_uri")
public class ControllerOne {

    @RequestMapping("/path")
    public String handlePath(){
        //do some logic
        return result;
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/same_uri")
public class ControllerTwo {

    @RequestMapping("/path")
    public String handlePath() {
        //do some logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

Defining different base paths to different Controllers would resolve the issue, for example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/first_controller")
public class ControllerOne {

    @RequestMapping("/path")
    public String handlePath(){
        //do some logic
        return result;
   }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/second_controller")
public class ControllerTwo {

    @RequestMapping("/path")
    public String handlePath() {
        //do some logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

You could target the desired method, of desired Controller using Postman with the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/first_controller/path
http://localhost:8080/second_controller/path
```

There is a way to use same @RequestMapping on different methods of the same Controller, as long as you uniquely identify each method by the parameters, as explained in this post: [Accessing multiple controllers with same request mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587254/accessing-multiple-controllers-with-same-request-mapping)