# Scalatra multiple routes for single action

Tags: scalatra

Currently i am trying to refactor a API without breaking changes. trying to migrate it from something like `host:port/foo/bar` to `host:port/bar`and im wondering if in Scalatra multiple routes are supported on a single action. I am trying it like:

```
get("/foo/bar", "/bar") {
 Ok(200) 
}
```

its returning with a empty response on either endpoint with a response code of 0 so i'm kind of puzzled. Is this supported in Scalatra?

I know in spring it'd look something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517486/4682816 but i am curious if there is something in Scalatra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalatra supports multiple transformers for a action, but it means the action in called if all transformers are matched. This is used to add additional conditions to the routing.

In your case, a request path can't match both `"/foo/bar"` and `"/bar"`, so I guess the action is never called.

You can do it instead as follows:

```
get("/foo/bar"){
  bar()
}

get("/bar"){
  bar()
}

private def bar() = {
  Ok(200)
}
```

or you can use regular expression:

```
get("^(/bar)|(/foo/bar)$".r){
  Ok(200)
}
```

Comment: that regex is exactly what i was looking for, but was overlooking, thank you